# Pagination For Admin Panel in PHP

Tags: php, panel, admin

i have no idea i tried to connect the DB with my panel but it gives some error any help would be appreciated...................................................................................................................

```
<?php
if (!(isset($pagenum)))
            {
            $pagenum = 1;
            }
            $qry = "SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 0,3";
            $result = mysqli_query($qry,$con);
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
            $page_rows = 3;
            $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

            if ($pagenum < 1)
            {
            $pagenum = 1; 
            }
            elseif ($pagenum > $last)
            {
            $pagenum = $last;
            }
                            $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;   


       $j=0;
       $qry ="SELECT * FROM posts $max";
       $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
            //This is where you display your query results
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
             $j++;

        echo "<p>";
            // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number Query and Results of pages
            echo " --Page $pagenum of $last--
            <p>";
            // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a 
            //link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't
            //then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.

            if ($pagenum == 1)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            echo " <a
            href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'>
            <<-First</a>
            ";
            echo " ";
            $previous = $pagenum-1;
            echo " <a
            href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?
            pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a>
            ";
            }
            //just a spacer
            echo " ---- ";
            //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page,
            //and then generating the Next and Last links
            if ($pagenum == $last)
            {
            }
            else {
            $next = $pagenum+1;
            echo " <a
            href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next
            -></a> ";
            echo " ";
            echo " <a
            href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last
            ->></a> ";
            }
                            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

Would do the trick if you are saving the $_POST username within the session upon successful login. We ideally really need to see the php code you are working with but this is a basic idea of how to accomplish what you're after

Comment: Assuming the value is stored in `$_SESSION` at all...

Comment: thx and wait leme try :)

Comment: Yeah i realised this after i posted it. It depends on how you've set up your code

Comment: thx a lot it worked but if som1 try to hack it if i put echo $_SESSION['password']; instead it would have shown it ? now how to prevent this?

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't save the password in the session. It should be a hashed string with a salt as well and is handled by the server. Should never be saved in plain text or in a session incase of session hijacking / other hacking